# How can I safetly reduce a partition's size?

Tags: partitioning

I have an NTFS partition, with very important data on it, of course, and I want to reduce its size to create a new partition.

The partition is around 40% used (60% free space).

I know we can use GParted to change the size of the partition, but... All of us know that the NTFS system has the naughty problem of "fragmentation", so, we can not to know where, on the physical surface, the data is.

So, my question is:

Does the system "re-alocate" the files (data), before to change the partition size (to avoid the risk to lose something)?

Or... I could lose data, anyway?

Greetings & Bleesings from Chile!!!!!!!

Juan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use GParted. It will move files. GParted is quite safe but it is always smart to make a backup before proceeding.